# Angular 2: Cannot get router parameter to work with service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I am building a site using `Angular 2`. I have a **detail page** where I access it by passing the id in the url (`http://localhost:3000/#/projectdetail/1`). I try to access a service to get the correct project by the id that I pass through. This project is saved in a **project variable**, but the variable is actually **undefined all the time**.

**This are the errors I get when I go to the detail page:**
[image: Errors]

This are the code pieces that I use (if you need more code just ask):

*The `projectdetail.page.html`:*

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>{{project.name}}</h1>
    <div>{{project.description}}</div>
</div>
```

*The `projectdetail.page.ts`:*

```
public project: Project;

constructor(private projectsService: ProjectsService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        this.addSlide();
    }
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.map(params => params['id']).subscribe((id) => {
        this.projectsService.getProject(id).then(project => this.project = project);
    });
}
```

*The `projects.service.ts`:*

```
getProject(id: number): Promise<Project> {
    return this.http.get(this.url).toPromise().then(x => x.json().data.filter(project => project.id === id)[0]).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting is from the template.
At the time of template render, `project` is not available yet.

Try to wrap it in an *ngIf to avoid this.

```
<div class="container-fluid" *ngIf="project">
    <h1>{{project.name}}</h1>
    <div>{{project.description}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Template rendering is happening before you are getting data,

what you need is to create an empty object for `project` property,

option 1:

```
   public project: Project =  new Project (); // Provided its a class.
```

option 2: 
If you may not instantiate Project (is an interface), you may use nullable properties

```
  {{project.name}}  -> {{project?.name}}
```

Hope this helps!!